# Eclipse generate copy constructor

Tags: java, eclipse

How to generate copy constructor in eclipse?

I know the method for generate contructor (using field or from super).

For example:

```
public class HeroInfo {
  private int hp;
  private float power;

  public HeroInfo() { // no-arg constructor
    super();
  }

  public HeroInfo(HeroInfo info){ // This is copy constructor
    super();
    this.hp = info.hp;
    this.power = info.power
  }

  ...
}
```

My Object contains a lot of variable, so its long to write.

So eclipse got a hotkey or a method for it ?

Comment: Really not sure what you want but you can always generate constructors, accessors and mutators by right clicking on the source code.

Comment: I use Microsoft Excel as my go to tool for such tasks(Read concatenation function)

Comment: Eclipse has no that build-in function, may be you can custom a template. Or you can use the 3rd library `lombok`.

Answer (score 25):

There is not an option to generate the source code for a copy constructor in Eclipse, but you can make the process easier using this strategy.

1. First generate a constructor for all fields by pressing: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>.
2. Then select the field assignments in the constructor and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open the find and replace dialog.
3. Replace `=[space]` with `=[space][Identifier].`.
4. Replace the arguments in the constructor signature with `[Type] [Identifier]`.

So for example say my generated constructor is:

```
    public Record(String name, String organization, String systemName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.organization = organization;
        this.systemName = systemName;
    }
```

I perform a find and replace on the selected text, replacing `=` with `= record.`  Resulting in:

```
    public Record(String name, String organization, String systemName) {
        this.name = record.name;
        this.organization = record.organization;
        this.systemName = record.systemName;
    }
```

Then replace the arguments in the signature with the identifier name:

```
    public Record(Record record) {
        this.name = record.name;
        this.organization = record.organization;
        this.systemName = record.systemName;
    }
```

Comment: Very simple and efficient way to create copy constructor in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in Eclipse.

Not only that, but a bug report requesting this functionality was closed with the status "**RESOLVED WONTFIX**". See [Bug 132676 - Source code feature: Add Copy Constructor](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=132676).

Note the final comment from the bug report:

> *The bug is marked as 'helpwanted' As soon as someone steps forward and offers to provide the feature we can reopen the bug.*