# Is there a shorthand to copy an object within a constructor?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, dagger-2, copy-constructor

Is there some way to achieve `this = that` in a constructor? `that` is an object that I want to copy (and thus is an object of the same class as `this`, `this` being the object reference).

```java
class Foo {

  private final Bar bar;

  public Foo() {
    Foo that = DaggerFactory.create().getFoo();
    // this = that; but it's not working!?
  }
  
  @Inject
  public Foo(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  // Other methods
}
```

I've seen examples of copy constructors where they copied the members one by one i.e. `this.bar = that.bar`. This is my last option as I've got a handful of members in the class, and I don't want to unnecessarily "clutter" my code.

P.S. I do want to instantiate the objects through the empty constructor as that's how AWS Lambda works (where I will be deploying this). So far I haven't found any way where I could get Lambda to use Dagger provided objects. If there is a better approach with respect to Lambda / Dagger that would also be great!

Comment: There is no way to make the constructor return an object that has been created with a factory method (such as `DaggerFactory.create().getFoo()` in your example). When the constructor runs, the object already exists, and you need to initialize it. Assigning to `this` is not possible in Java.

Comment: No, there is no shorthand.

Comment: you might have a look at lombok's Builder(toBuilder=true) which gives you a builder which does what you need.

Comment: @juwil Cool! Will look into

Comment: @Jesper Let's forget the factory for a bit. What if it was a regular copy constructor? Is copying the members one by one the only option?

Comment: @Michael I guess that's it then :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clever (shortcut / shorthand) way to write a copy constructor in Java.  At the source code level you must assign the fields one at a time.

Normally, I would just "bite the bullet" and write the code.  But there are a couple of other alternatives:

- Your IDE *may* have a way to generate a copy constructor.  (Eclipse doesn't, but apparently you can generate a regular constructor for all field, and then do some clever search-replace stuff on the generated code; see [Eclipse generate copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467730/))
- You could conceivably write some reusable code that copies fields from one object to another using reflection.  This is rather inefficient, but it might be acceptable if you have to deal with classes that have a ridiculous number of fields.
- You could use the `clone()` mechanism instead.

Comment: Would you happen to know anything similar to Lombok's `@NoArgsConstructor` for copy constructor? Lombok doesn't seem to have it

Comment: I could then use `this(that)`

Comment: If you are asking about Java or Lombok?  This question and my answer is about Java.

Comment: Yeah the questions's about Java, and unfortunately based on the comments and your answer, there is no shortcut. So I asked if you knew, based on your XP, of any annotations

Comment: Coz IDE way would still have "code clutter" (at least IMO), reflections I'm not so sure of, and `clone()` isn't quite the answer to my question

Comment: Well yes.  That's why I described those things as **alternatives** rather than solutions.  (And I know that `clone()` isn't a drop-in replacement for a copy constructor.)